# How to center a play button on a responsive video element

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I am making a video player using the HTML5 video element, I have a play button that will start the video. However my problem is how I can get the play button to sit in the centre of the video. Using position or margins to push the button into the centre of the video will not work, as when you resize the window and therefore the player, the play button will move out of place.

I've tried using positioning - left/top etc, and I've used to margins with the same concept, however these do not work with a responsive video player, I'm lost with how to deal with this and was wondering if anyone had suggestions.

Comment: Please edit the question and include the HTML as well. Just the CSS isn’t useful as a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @asobak I can share some code, but the idea of the question was that what I have already tried will not work and I was wondering if people knew a way to deal with this. However, I edit the question with a video player and button

Comment: Hi @Team Ecko , you need to use media queries of CSS for that. Check my code below in answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For centering any thing (img, icon, text etc)

```
.parent_item{
   position: relative;
}
.center_item {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

`.parent_item` is your video wrapper class while `.center_item` is you play icon or button, Also it's responsive.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media queries of CSS for adding padding and margins for a different size for different devices.
Following media queries will help you to code. Put your padding and margin CSS code inside it for varies device viewports.

```
    <style>

/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {  

  /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

 }

 /* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

 }

 /* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

 } 

 /* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {  

  /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

 }      

 /* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

  /* Your CSS Code for this device size */ 

 }

 /* According to Mobile Orientation */
 @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {   

    /* Your CSS Code for this device orientation */    

 }

</style>
```

Comment: This doesnt quite solve my problem as the window can be resized, when the window is it might still be in the same width category but the play button will be slightly off centered, from the video which is my problem. Im editing the question with some code if that helps. THanks anyway

Comment: Welcome, @TeamEcko , Without your code, I guess that my code will help you. But if its not help then I need your code to solve your query.